# Proving the following Expected Value using Matrix Algebra

Tags: probability

Suppose we have the following information:

- $y \sim N(X\beta, V)$
- $\hat{e} = y - X\hat{\beta}$
- $\hat{\beta} = (X^T V^{-1} X)^{-1} X^T V^{-1} y$

**I am trying to prove the following relationship:**

$$\text{Cov}(x^T V^{-1}y, \hat{e}) = 0$$

I thought that maybe I can do this from first principles:

$$Cov(x,y) = E(( X - E(x)]*[Y - E(Y)) )$$

When I tried to apply this to my question, I got the following:

$$\text{Cov}(x^T V^{-1}y, \hat{e}) = E(x^T V^{-1}y^ty  - x^T V^{-1}y X\hat{\beta} - x^T V^{-1}X \beta y + x^T V^{-1}XX \beta \hat{\beta})$$

From here, I am not sure how this can simplified to prove that this is 0.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The correct formula is $\text{Cov}(X, Y) = E((X - E(X))(Y - E(Y))^T)$.